# Is there a better design pattern for this requirement?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm dealing with a design pattern problem: In a library system, admin can grant the certain permission of user information management (e.g., creating or searching user info) to other departments or schools. So I tried to use the visitor pattern. Users like teachers and students are the subclass of User and the admin or other department is the visitor.

However, more user types can be added is also the requirement. It is not suitable to add more elements in the visitor pattern. What design pattern should I choose instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of what you write, I think you're overengineering your solution. What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Visitor visits the objects in a Composite structure and uses double dispatch in order to choose which method to be invoked. All you seem to need in your problem is a `User` superclass with a `setAccess` method, and sublclasses such as `Teacher` and `Student`.